# Isolate or hide specific parts of an object in edit mode

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

I am just modeling an Audi R8 in Blender. I've already modeled more than half of the car.
I've also modeled the front and now I want to model the back. But this is a bit difficult because when I am in the "Back" View I see all the stuff I modeled on the front.

So is there a way to blend out separate parts of an object in edit mode?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can isolate a specific part of a model to work on by going into *Edit* mode and using <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> (this toggles the isolated selection on/off) and drawing a square outline to focus on a specific area .

One advantage/disadvantage of this (depending on what you need) over just hiding other parts of your mesh with <kbd>H</kbd> is that the entire model can still be affected by other tools such as ring cuts or proportional editing.

Answer (score 39):

You can hide parts of a mesh in edit mode and you can hide whole objects in object mode:

- press <kbd>H</kbd> to hide the selection
- press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to hide the elements which are not selected
- press <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to unhide everything

You can also access these functions in the viewport in the menu via Mesh->Show/Hide.

Comment: I really wouldn't recommend this to a beginner as it can lead to a plethora of problems further on. Note that if you use these, and you use a tool such as proportional edit or add edge loops, it will _not_ update or affect the hidden parts of the mesh. So if OP say adds a few edgeloops at the back and works on this for a few minutes, after showing everything again, you might be left with a large ngon or a very untidy mesh.

Comment: Thanks for this hint but this didn't worked if I am in orthographic view and back.

Comment: Tested and it works for me in orthographic view too. However note that parts of a mesh are only hidden when its being edited. If the object switches back to object mode the full mesh is being shown. It's an easy way to show/hide several elements blocking the view on the fly. Regarding invisible geometry i read that the devs do not want the user to make changes to it because the user does not notice and may be doing something unintended. Anyway other options have been pointed out.

Comment: it's working for me on Blender 2.75 but when i unhide, everything become selected :(

Answer (score 13):

Besides using Show/Hide feature, you can also use **Mask** modifier and toggle the last two buttons as shown in the image below, which is more flexable by using vertex group:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Go into local view (numpad /) https://en.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/3D_interaction/Navigating/Global_or_Local_View

Comment: Works in Blender 2.8 too