# Possible to keep parts of an object hidden while in edit mode for a different object?

Tags: modeling

Blender 2.9. I'm wondering if it's possible to keep part of a character mesh hidden whilst working on it's armature in edit mode. My character is in A-pose and the hands/arms/fingers obstruct the view of the torso bones while in side orthographic. I can work around it, but jumping into side view to work on torso controls would be nice.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Does this help ? https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/48200/86891

Comment: Can also use a clipping region Alt+B (and Alt+B again to remove it)

Comment: @Gorgious this was the first thing I tried. It seems as though each mask modifier can only hold one vertex group. Unfortuantely with all the fingers (3 vertex groups each) I ended needing about 40 mask modifiers. Was a tad bit unmanageable. It also seems I can't add all the verts I need hidden into one vertex group without affecting my current weight painting? Thanks for your reply!

Comment: @lemon Thank you, this seems like a good way to go about it. I wish it could store the last used clipping region so it can be toggled, but will work just fine. Thanks again!

Comment: You can assign selections to completely new vertex groups at weight 1, which have nothing to do with bones or deformation, just for hiding?

Comment: @RobinBetts you...are absolutely correct. No idea why I thought they couldn't be in multiple vertex groups. I was definitely overthinking it. Thanks so much!